# Error 1064 - SQL syntax for an INSERT statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to execute this query:

```
insert into lvl.tb_jogos a (a.Tags,a.Nome,a.Descricao,a.IdCategoria,a.Tipo)
values
(
  (select b.keywords,b.name,b.`desc`,b.cat,b.`type`
   from level2.games b, lvl.tb_jogos a
   where b.name LIKE `%12 Holes of X-Mas%`
  )
)
```

But SQL return this message:

> Error SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right symtax to use near 'a(a.Tags,a.Nome,a.Descricao,a.IdCategoria,a.Tipo) values (
>     (select b.keywords at line 1

Can you help me?

Comment: dont supply an alias on table when inserting.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the word `VALUES` and then you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Replace backticks with single quotes, from this:

```
LIKE `%12 Holes of X-Mas%`
```

to this:

```
LIKE '%12 Holes of X-Mas%'
```

Also remove extra VALUES and parentheses. Your statement should be:

```
INSERT INTO lvl.tb_jogos (Tags, Nome, Descricao, IdCategoria, Tipo)
SELECT b.keywords, b.name, b.desc, b.cat, b.type
FROM level2.games b, lvl.tb_jogos a
WHERE b.name LIKE '%12 Holes of X-Mas%'
```